# How to add and update a value in pandas df each time a new value is found?

Tags: python

Most of the the other questions regarding updating values in pandas df are focused on appending a new column or just updating the cell with a new value (i.e. replacing it). My question is a bit different. Assuming my df already has values in it, and I find a new value, I need to add it into the cell to update its value. Example if a cell already has 5 and I found the value 10 in my file that corresponds to that column/row, the value should now be 15.

But I am having trouble writing this bit of code and even getting values to show up in my dataframe.

I have a dictionary, for example:

```
id_dict={'Treponema': ['162'], 'Leptospira': ['174'], 'Azospirillum': ['192'], 'Campylobacter': ['195', '197', '199', '201'], 'Pseudomonas': ['287'], 'NONE': ['2829358', '2806529']}
```

And I have sample id files that contain ids and the number of times those ids showed up in a previous file where the first value is the count and the second value is the id.

```
cat Sample1_idsummary.txt
1,162
15,174
4,195
5,197
6,201
10,2829358
```

Some of the ids have the same key in id_dict and I need to create a dataframe like the following:

```
    Sample  Treponema  Leptospira  Azospirillum  Campylobacter  Pseudomonas  NONE
0   sample1     1          15             0             15           0     10
```

Here is my script, but my issue is that my output is always zero for all columns.

```
samplefile=sys.argv[1]
sample_ID=samplefile.split("_")[0] ## get just ID name
def get_ids_counts(id_dict,samplefie):
        '''Obtain a table of id counts from the samplefile.'''
        column_names=["Sample"]
        column_names.extend([x for x in list(id_dict.keys())])
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
        df["Sample"]=[sample_ID]
    with open(samplefile) as sf: # open the sample taxid count file
              for line in sf:
                      id = line.split(",")[1] # the taxid (multiple can hit the same lineage info)
                      idcount = int(line.split(",")[0]) # the count from uniq
                    # For all keys in the dict, if that key is in the sample id file use the count from the id file
                    # Otherwise all keys not found in the file are "0" in the df
                       if id in id_dict:
                              df[list(id_dict.keys())[list(id_dict.values().index(id))]] = idcount
    return df.fillna(0)
```

It's the very last if statement that is confusing me. How to make idcount add each time it gives the same key and why do I always get zeros filled in?

**The below mentioned method worked! Here is the updated code:**

```
def get_ids_counts(id_dict,samplefie):
        '''Obtain a table of id counts from the samplefile.'''
        df = pd.DataFrame([id_dict]).stack().explode().to_frame('id').droplevel(0).reset_index().astype({'id':int})
        iddf = pd.read_csv(samplefile, sep=",", names=["count","id"])
        df=df.merge(iddf, how='outer').fillna(0).groupby('index')['count'].sum().to_frame(sample_ID).T
        return df
```

**And the output, which is still not coming up right:**

```
index      0  Azospirillaceae  Campylobacteraceae  Leptospiraceae  NONE  Pseudomonadacea  Treponemataceae
mini   106.0              0.0                20.0             0.0   0.0              0.0              5.0
```

**UPDATE 2**

With the code below and using my proper files I've managed to get the table but cannot for the life of me get the "NONE" column to show up anymore. Any suggestions? My output is essentially every key value with proper counts but "NONE" disappears.

Comment: Because of `df.fillna(0)`, all the null values are filled with zeros. Also in  the dataframe you have provided, why `Treponema` has 162 i.e. the count but others have ID?

Comment: Sorry that was my typo! It should be 1. Fixed

Comment: I also tried without df.fillna(0) but I got the same thing, all were just NaNs. But I need every single key in the id_dict() to be in the table and if any of those keys are not found in sample1, then I need it to be a value of 0. This is because I have to do this for over 100 samples and later will append them all into one giant dataframe.

Comment: Do you want the for example `5,197`-> 5 values for `id` 197? Or you want to have just a single value, the latest one?

Comment: A single value, all added up. Each cell will only have 1 value once finished. So Camylobacter has 3 ids found in sample1, their count values added together will be 15, so 15 should appear in the final dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that way iteratively, you can more automate and use pandas to perform those operations.

Start by creating the dataframe from `id_dict`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([id_dict]).stack().explode().to_frame('id').droplevel(0).reset_index()\
     .astype({'id': int})

           index       id
0      Treponema      162
1     Leptospira      174
2   Azospirillum      192
3  Campylobacter      195
4  Campylobacter      197
5  Campylobacter      199
6  Campylobacter      201
7    Pseudomonas      287
8           NONE  2829358
9           NONE  2806529
```

Read the count/id text file into a data frame:

```py
idDF = pd.read_csv('Sample1_idsummary.txt', sep=',' , names=['count',  'id'])

   count       id
0      1      162
1     15      174
2      4      195
3      5      197
4      6      201
5     10  2829358
```

Now outer merge both the dataframes, fill `NaN`'s with 0, then `groupby` index, and call `sum` and create the dataframe calling `to_frame` and passing count as column name, finally transpose the dataframe:

```py
df.merge(idDF, how='outer').fillna(0).groupby('index')['count'].sum().to_frame('Sample1').T
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
index    Azospirillum  Campylobacter  Leptospira  NONE  Pseudomonas  Treponema
Sample1           0.0           15.0        15.0  10.0          0.0        1.0
```

Comment: Hmm how to show you my output as a comment...mine ended up looking very different from yours.

Comment: Make sure the dictionary being used to create `df` has the same format as `id_dict`, did you try the above code on the sample data in question? You can add it to the question itself.

Comment: Well the dictionary I gave you is just a minor sample of the dictionary I use. It has the same format and everything just a TONNN more key and values.

Comment: Well let's see how it looks, you can add the resulting dataframe at the end of the question.

Comment: okay posted as an edit to my question! Thanks!

Comment: That's `df` only, you need to read `idDF`, then do the merger. Follow the answer step-by-step.

Comment: Ahh got it. I should have saved df.merge as the df variable. So df=df.merge....

Comment: Yeah, but what you have is each id iteratively after reading the file, but I've instead created a dataframe from that file so that it can directly be merged without the need to iterate one by one.

Comment: Yes, You need to return the result or assign it back.

Comment: Yup! thanks! Is there also a way to change the values into just ints without decimals. Not a huge deal but I'm not sure if that will cause downstream analysis issues.

Comment: You can do that after filling `NaN` with `0`, because `NaN` can not be represented by `integer` type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234930/discussion-between-curiousdude-and-thepyguy).